# Codeigniter Link isn't working

Tags: php, codeigniter

The problem is that I am redirecting my function from one controller to another and I don't know why it isn't getting redirected there but is straightly getting out to the login `page(RegistrationController)` when I use the redirect function but when I load the view then it works.

Consider the following snippet. I want it to be redirected to the `AdminController` but it isn't getting redirected there. I have a view in the `AdminController`.

Beside this, the links in that view are also not working, they are also loading the `RegisterationController` whenever gets clicked.

```
<?php

    class RegistrationController extends CI_Controller{
        function validate_credentials(){

        $username = $this->input->post('hotelEmail');
        $password = $this->input->post('hotelPassword');

        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $query = $this->AdminModel->validate($username, $password);

        if($query) // If the user's credentials validated . . .
        {
            $data = array(
                'hotel_email'   => $this->input->post('hotelEmail'),
                'hotel_id'  => true
                );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            redirect('AdminController');
        }else{

            $this->session->set_flashdata('wrong_credentials', 'Wrong Username or Password!');
            $this->load->view('login'); 

        }

    }
?>
```

The class of the view controller is extended from the AuthenticationController which is as following

```
    <?php

    class AuthenticationController extends CI_Controller{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->checkSession();
        }

        public function checkSession(){
            if(!$this->session->set_userdata('hotel_id')){
                redirect('RegistrationController/');
                exit();
            }
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: I think session are not created, just echo print_r($this->session->userdata);

Comment: @whoami thanks for ur time. but could you help me how should i check that whether session is created or not?

Comment: @whoami that gave me the following result:

Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1502471785 [hotel_email] => a@z [hotel_id] => 1 ) 1

Comment: @MoizArif yes i did!

Comment: You are naming your controller wrong first letter only must be upper case file and class name http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the **set_** from **set_userdata** from the *checkSession()* function and you are good to go!

Comment: this is exactly the right answer!! thumbs up for you

Comment: @NOONE http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Answer (score 0):

Start by loading the session in the controller or `autoload.php`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

Next, call `validate_credentials` to create a session if the user credentials are correct.

Next, call this function:

```
public function checksession()
{
    print_r($this->session->userdata); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **set_userdata** in place of **userdata**

**User this code**

```
public function checkSession(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('hotel_id')){
        redirect('RegistrationController/');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Moiz bro, u have no idea how thankful am I to you. I swear. I truely am in debt to you.

Comment: Nice to hear that this helps you.. :) :)

Comment: Sometimes its happen 